# Angular using apache with google analytics

Tags: angularjs, apache, google-analytics

Okay ive been attempting this for days without any results and i really hope that some of you can help me.

I have problems with google not indexing my website meaning it cannot see the content of my website.

My website is an angular application.

So i saw this post [ng-newletter](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/serious-angular-seo.html) saying that i could use apache so my configs are as follow:

```
$ a2enmod proxy
$ a2enmod proxy_http
```

Which enables proxy

Then i have edited my virtualhost with the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.mydomain.dk
    ServerAlias mydomain.dk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain/

    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/%1? [NC,L]

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf


    <Directory /var/www/mydomain/>
             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Now when i attempt to run the google-bot-simulator i get some odd response:

No matter which url i go to it tells me that it has redirected back to `index`

and i am now unable to go to `www.mydomain/subsite` without getting a `404`

So what am i doing wrong?

**Answer from google**

```
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 17 Sep 2015 13:13:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Location: http://mydomain.dk/products
Content-Length: 315
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://mydomain.dk/products">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at www.mydomain.dk Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```